# xslt: How can I apply two templates to the same node during processing?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XSL template that matches any element with a `<var>` child:

```
<xsl:template match="*[var]">
    <xsl:copy >
        <xsl:attribute name="editable">
            <xsl:for-each select="var[@attr]">
                <xsl:value-of
                              select="concat(@attr,
                                             substring(' ',
                                                       1 div (position()!=last())))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="constraints">
            <xsl:for-each select="var[@ok]">
                <xsl:value-of
                              select="concat(@attr,':',@ok,
                                             substring(';',
                                                       1 div (position()!=last())))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- if this is an <a> then we have to put the stuff inside it inside it -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It concatenates the `attr`s of the var elements into the `editable` attribute of the parent; and the `ok`s into `constraint`s.

Then I have a template that matches any `<field>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="field">
     <span>
        <xsl:attribute name="field">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="boolean(@name)">
                   <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

This simply converts it to `<span field="name">` with a name the same of the field, if the field had one, or else 'true'.

Problem I'm having is, `*[var]` matches a field if the field has a `<var>` as a child. But what I want to happen is for the `*[var]` to match *first*, and then `field` to match *as well*, but *afterwards*.

Currently, with an input of

```
<field name="field1">
    <var attr="class" ok="small,smaller" />
    Text
</field>
```

I get

```
<field name="field1" editable="class" constraints="class:small,smaller">
    Text
</field>
```

But I want

```
<span field="field1" editable="class" constraints="class:small,smaller">
    Text
</span>
```

I found some answers on SO about doing two passes but I'm not sure whether it's the right answer, nor quite how to implement the answers I did find. How should I approach this, and if there's an easy answer, what is it? :)

TIA 
Altreus

Answer (score 7):

If you want to apply two templates to the same node, you can use xsl:next-match: from the highest-priority rule that matches a node, you can call xs:next-match to invoke the next-highest, and so on. You can adjust the priorities "by hand", of course, using the priority attribute on xsl:template.

There are several other possibilities here:

(a) it seems to me from a quick glance that the processing of the "var" element could be done in a template that matches the var element rather than *[var], in which case it can be invoked by xsl:apply-templates in the usual way

(b) the first template can invoke the second using apply-templates in a special mode

(c) the first template can construct a temporary element in a variable and then apply-templates to that.

Comment: From all my searching nothing turned up this next-match magic. I did try some of the things you suggested but I daresay I was not doing it right :)

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[var]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="makeVarAttribute"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="field" priority="1">
        <span field="{concat(@name,
                             substring('true',
                                       1 div not(@name)
                                      )
                            )}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="makeVarAttribute"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="var"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="makeVarAttribute"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[var]"
                  name="makeVarAttribute"
                  mode="makeVarAttribute">
        <xsl:attribute name="editable">
            <xsl:for-each select="var[@attr]">
                <xsl:value-of
                         select="concat(@attr,
                                        substring(' ',
                                                  1 div (position()!=last())
                                                 )
                                       )"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="constraints">
            <xsl:for-each select="var[@ok]">
                <xsl:value-of
                         select="concat(@attr,':',@ok,
                                        substring(';',
                                                  1 div (position()!=last())
                                                 )
                                       )"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<span field="field1" editable="class" constraints="class:small,smaller">
    Text
</span>
```

**Note**: the use of `@priority` because `*[var]` pattern has higher default priority than `field`, encapsulation of common content template in a named template, the use of `@mode` for process a node twice (first the `span` transformation, then the attributes population **if** there is a `var` child).

**Edit**: I didn't see the [xslt-2.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-2.0). This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[var]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="makeVarAttribute"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="field" priority="1">
        <span field="{(@name,'true')[1]}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="makeVarAttribute"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="var"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="makeVarAttribute"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[var]"
                  name="makeVarAttribute"
                  mode="makeVarAttribute">
        <xsl:attribute name="editable" select="var/@attr"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="constraints"
                       select="var[@ok]/concat(@attr,':',@ok)"
                       separator=";"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: sequence handling in, function as last step in expression, `@separator`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="var">
    <xsl:attribute name="editable">
            <xsl:value-of select="@attr"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="constraints">
            <xsl:value-of  select="concat(@attr,':',@ok)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="field">
  <span>
    <xsl:attribute name="field">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name">
               <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Moving the var element out like this was a thing I considered; but I'm not sure how I'd perform the second concatenation - the one with the semicolon. I'm afraid I didn't fully understand the original - it Just Worked - and I've not taken the time to sit down and work it out yet :o! Maybe at the end of this iteration of the project...